# Apache cordova plugin will support external website inside the phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm planning to launch external website to phonegap. In this cases, Is cordova plugin will support?

Comment: Do you need to open the web page inside your phonegap app?

Answer (score 0):

Add the InAppBrowser plugin for allowing to open external links so you will be able to come back to your application :

```
<script>
function openExternal(elem) {
    window.open(elem.href, "_system");
    return false; // Prevent execution of the default onClick handler 
}
</script>
<a href="https://www.twitter.com" onClick="javascript:return openExternal(this)">Twitter</a>
```